# Changing default rounding and alignment for all attribute table columns in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table

I am on ArcDesktop 10.3 and wondering if there is a way to change the default rounding decimals and alignment numbers for all columns across all attribute tables?  ie. a global default?[image]

In the image above it is the two circled values I would like to change the default of so they always come up 1 decimal place and 0 Alignment spaces

The problem happens when links to the data-driven FC are broken and subsequently the link to the joined table breaks, and I have to break these links frequently as I point the MXD to different geodatabases.  After I re-path things the rounding and alignment values default back to 6 and 12.

I did find a workaround where I can save a layer file of the data-driving feature class linked to the joined spreadsheet, then make sure other MXD's are closed and add that layer file to a new MXD it does come in with the table joined and the decimal/alignment settings retained, but it would be nice if I could just know that the numbers would default to this behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by "12 right aligned characters" and "0 right alignment characters"? Numbers are right aligned, text is left aligned. Are you saying you need the values to be text?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your data in a screen shot or two to illustrate the problem.

Comment: When you say data-driving do you mean Data driven pages?

Comment: yes, data driven pages

Comment: You could try the Advanced ArcMap Settings utility. I took a quick look and didn't see anything for this. https://goo.gl/ZcsndP

Comment: I'm not aware of an answer better than that on the duplicate.